# Garuda Linux application style not changing in some apps when global theme changed

Tags: kde, gtk, theme, garuda-linux

I tried to change the default Garuda theme to other themes such as Orchis, WhiteSur, Material Dark KDE, etc. and almost everything was working fine, however, I noticed that some applications like Dolphin, Terminal, KDE Connect Settings, etc. had Garuda's sweet application style instead of that of the new theme. So the application style didn't mix well with the new theme. I also tried to manually install and apply other application styles from the Appearance settings but there was almost no effect.
Some apps like Settings and System Monitor have perfectly synced with the new theme tho. So I wonder what's the problem here is.

I am currently using WhiteSur Dar Theme and the application style is Kvantum. I have read somewhere about Kvantum manager and idk if that can fix this issue with modifications but I have no idea how to use that.

As a new user, I wasn't allowed to upload screenshots, so here is the [link to the image.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1066400981555884042/1124551681510735973/image.png)
[image: Screenshot of different application style]

Any help is appreciated!